# Calling list from another list in function works but not outside the function in R

Tags: r, lapply

This is an exercise from the DataCamp and I am asking this question here to simply understand the behaviour behind calling named lists.

The goal here is to create a function to access named object `$timestamp` within a list called `logs`, then use `lapply` and print only `$timestamp` from `logs`. What I don't understand is why R behaves differently when calling the same command within and outside the function.

Head of logs looks like this:

```
head(logs, 2)
[[1]]
[[1]]$success
[1] TRUE
[[1]]$details
[[1]]$details$message
[1] "check"
[[1]]$timestamp
[1] "2015-09-14 23:01:07 UTC"
[[2]]
[[2]]$success
[1] TRUE
[[2]]$details
[[2]]$details$message
[1] "all good"
[[2]]$timestamp
[1] "2015-09-15 00:00:13 UTC"
```

We need to access all `$timestamp` objects in the list above. To do this, a function has to be created:

```
get_timestamp = function(x) {return(x[["timestamp"]])}
```

The body of the function uses `x[["timestamp"]]`. What I do not understand is, why calling directly either:

```
logs[["timestamp"]]
get_timestamp(logs)
```

Results in:

```
NULL
```

But calling:

```
lapply(logs, get_timestamp)
```

Returns all the timestamps which is the goal of the whole exercise.

```
[[1]]
[1] "2015-09-14 23:01:07 UTC"
[[2]]
[1] "2015-09-15 00:00:13 UTC"
```

Thank you for explaining this.

Comment: Easy: `logs` doesn't have any `timestamp` element. Instead, `logs` is a (not named) `list` whose elements are lists themselves and *those* lists have the `timestamp` element. So, `logs$timestamp` is `NULL`, but `logs[[1]]$timestamp` is not (see now why?). The `lapply` function is meant to apply a function to each element of a list. So it evaluates `logs[[1]]$timestamp`, then `logs[[2]]$timestamp` and so on.

Comment: Because `lapply()` takes each element of your list and then search the tag `timestamp`. But what you do when you are doing : `logs[["timestamp"]]`is not the same because `timestamp` is embedded in each element of your list  and you can see it with the notations returned by R. So look at `[[1]]$timestamp`, it means that you take your the 1st element of your list and then you search within the tag `timestamp` so what you should have written is : `logs[[1]]["timestamp"]`  or `logs[[1]]$timestamp`